# SQL Server Access Question

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, connection

I have a machine that is only able to connect to a 2008 SQL server sporadically.  I created a monitoring script that I have automated to attempt a connection (via sqlsrv driver and php) every 15 mins.   This script has ran fine for the last two weeks but recently it has been reporting a SQL server going down.   On extensive investigation I am able to connect to it from every other machine consistently except for the machine automating the monitoring script.   This script also connects to two other SQL servers (both are sql server 2005) without any problems.   Here is what I have tried to resolve the failures:
1.  Reset both machines (serveral times)
2.  Attempted connections via several different logins countless times (including sa).
3.  Deleted and recreated logins and attempted to connect.
4.  Turned off windows firewall (SQL server is running on win2k8)

This is the error I get when I cant connect: http://pastebin.com/9d80mAyV

Typically it wont work for about 5 attempts (spaced 15 mins apart) then it will work for 1 attempt. Then it fails for another 5 attempts.   There is no absolute consistency.

My thoughts is that it has blacklisted my client from connecting too often.  Is this possible? How could I resolve this problem? Any other thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at your server logs? They might provide some indication as to whether the cause is due to resource limitations (a possible cause listed in the error message).

Comment: One more thought after talking with a colleage...the error code 64 "typically means the connection has been either locally or remotely reset. The network dropping packets may very well be a cause for this error among other things (such as the peer has abortively closed the connection for some reason)." So, you might want to investigate bad network hardware (like a malfunctioning NIC or switch). The fact that you are seeing this on only this one machine supports this possibility too.

Answer (score 0):

A few more details needed:

1. What are you using to connect? is it an application or management studio (what version?)
2. Where are the servers located? i.e. are you on the same network?

You can try to increase your connection timeout. If you are connecting from management studio, then you can do this in the server registration properties.

Alternatively, you can setup sql monitoring on the server itself, and it will email you when it goes down.

Comment: The connection is being done in php using the sqlsrv api from microsoft.  The server is located on an external network but we have a fiber connection to it and teh ping is less then 3ms.   I increased the timeout on both the server and the script with no luck.